# How to undo auto-formatted html wrapping in Visual Studio?

Tags: html, visual-studio, formatting, text-formatting

I have been editing HTML file in Visual Studio. There were many li elements in it. All of them were formatted this way (no matter how long the text was):

```
    <li>ExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExample</li>
```

But after sometime (I didn't notice when exactly) the code has ben auto-formatted  by VS (or accidentaly by me?) and looks like this:

```
      <li>
           ExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExample
           LineWrapped
      </li>
```

I wonder is there any way to go back to the previous format without wrapping and having everything in one line?

Comment: This is a completely off topic question. Please refer the below link on what questions are supposed to be asked here in stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Also I believe the answer for this question can easily found via googling. Always research first before asking a question here.

Comment: I did a research before asking but didn't find anything that could help me. There are similar problems I found, but they are not the same. For example: Tools >> Options >> Text Editor >> All Languages >> General >> Word Wrap is not selected, and that was the issue in the other case.